# How to assign "Storage Blob Data Reader" role to a user/group in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

As per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#azure-roles-for-blobs-and-queues) there is a pre-defined role called "*Storage Blob Data Reader*" for storage accounts. However, this role doesn't show up in the drop down when I am trying to add a role assignment in the portal.

**I expect to see this (image copied from [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#assign-an-azure-built-in-role)):**

[image]

**What I actually see:** (Notice, there is no role called Storage Blob Data Reader when I search for "Storage" in the role dropdown)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by comparing this to a different storage account. Storage Account (classic) doesn't support *Storage Blob Data Reader* role. StorageV2 does. The type is listed as "*Account kind*" in the *Overview* page of the storage account.

Comment: On Thursdays, Azure is pure science. On Fridays and alternate Tuesdays, it's decoder rings and mystic chants.